# Purpose of $1 and $2 in this Perl regex: s/^([^,]+,)ab.([^,]+,)(?:[^,]+,)/$1$2/

Tags: regex, perl

Can anyone please suggest me the meaning of below Perl regex:

```
$_ =~ s/^([^,]+,)ab.([^,]+,)(?:[^,]+,)/$1$2/;
```

What is the role of `$1` and `$2` and how these variables are defined?

Comment: That does not look like valid perl code.  I am guessing there should be a `s` before the first `/`, and probably the `=` should be `=~`. Please recheck what you have typed in --- ideally copy and paste from the script you found it in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The regular expression means:

```
^          Start of string
(          Start of capturing group -> $1
 [^,]+     Any character except ",", one or more times
 ,         A literal ","
)          End of capturing group
ab         "ab"
.          Any character
([^,]+,)   Same as previously -> $2
(?:        Start a non-capturing group
    [^,]+, Same as previously
)          End group
```

Each capturing group is placed into a numbered variable in the order they appear in the RegEx

Comment: Since the *dot all* modifier `s` is not set, `.` does only represent any character except the line break characters.

Answer (score 6):

The $1 and $2 variables are match variables.

In a Regex, when something is surrounded by parentheses, that part of the regex (if it matches) gets stored in a $n variable.

So for example:  /(\d+),(\w+)/  Would match something like 123,xyz with 123 being assigned to $1, and xyz being assigned in $2.   They are assigned in the order that they appear in the regex.

Note that a "?:" after the leading parentheses i.e. (?: ...), tells the regex to not save that matched value in a $n variable.

Here is example code that demonstrates what your regex is doing using Perl.  Note that it appears you're missing the leading s (for substitution) on the regex within your question.

**File: test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print $ARGV[0], "\n";
$ARGV[0] =~ s/^([^,]+,)ab.([^,]+,)(?:[^,]+,)/$1$2/;
print "\$1 = $1\n";
print "\$2 = $2\n";
print $ARGV[0], "\n";
```

**Execute:**

```
%> ./test.pl str1,ab.str2,str3,str4,
str1,ab.str2,str3,str4,
$1 = str1,
$2 = str2,
str1,str2,str4,
```

Comment: Note that there doesn’t need to be a literal dot in the subject since the `.` represents any arbitrary character (except line break characters).